# Which Windows Phone restrictions makes benchmarking a challenge?

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile, apps

> Because of some restrictions in Windows Phone, AnTuTu Benchmark's algorithms are not exactly the same as the Android version.

What does AnTuTu mean by Windows Phone restrictions? Are there certain low-level features in Android available to AnTuTu that are not available in Windows Phone? Or are there certain workload limitations placed on any application by Windows Phone preventing a true benchmarking at least like the one in Android?

Answer (score 2):

Android is an unrestricted platform, and an app can happily come along and do whatever it wants, including running in the background and all sorts of other things.

Windows Phone has restrictions on what a third party developer can do, such as using resources in the background.

From a development point of view, reviewers *could* use cross platform tools to build benchmarks such as Unity to fairly compare performance of real world scenarios, across platforms